# Why are numeric_limits<time_point<...>>::max() and time_point<...>::max() different?

Tags: c++17

I was recently experimenting with `std::chrono::time_point`, and was very surprised by the behaviour of numeric_limits with time points.  Specifically, I do not understand why `std::numeric_limits<...>::max()` and `std::timepoint<...>::max()` are different, and moreover, why `std::numeric_limits<...>::max()` is the default value.

```
// All the following static asserts are valid.

using timepoint = std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock>;
constexpr static auto max_nanos = std::chrono::nanoseconds(std::numeric_limits<int64_t>::max());
constexpr static auto zero_nanos = std::chrono::nanoseconds(0);
constexpr static auto default_time_point = timepoint();
constexpr static auto numeric_max_time_point = std::numeric_limits<timepoint>::max();
constexpr static auto explicit_max_time_point = timepoint::max();

static_assert(default_time_point == timepoint(zero_nanos), "");
static_assert(default_time_point == numeric_max_time_point, ""); // !?
static_assert(explicit_max_time_point != numeric_max_time_point, ""); //!?
static_assert(explicit_max_time_point == timepoint(max_nanos), "");
```

Can someone please explain this behaviour to me?

Comment: What compiler/standard library are you using?  I tried compiling your code with apple-clang/libc++ v 14, and I got compile errors (not static assertion failures) starting with `timepoint(zero_nanos)`

Comment: @MarshallClow It compiles fine on godbolt using gcc 13.1: https://godbolt.org/z/hWsj1zEhW

Comment: And fails on Godbolt with clang and libc++: https://godbolt.org/z/nKhM7o1rj

Comment: To make the code in the question portable, give the first line `nanoseconds` precision like this: `using timepoint = std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock, std::chrono::nanoseconds>;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: `numeric_limits` is not your friend here.  If you use `numeric_limits` on non-arithmetic types (such as `time_point` and `nanoseconds`), you get a structure filled with default values (mostly all zeros)

See https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/bc6bd0d608da1609c1caeb04ab795a83720add55/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/limits#L312 for the implementation in libstdc++